# Temporary lines in objects created at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, firemonkey-style

When I create objects at runtime in FireMonkey, some lines are shown on the sides of the objects.

The image below is a `TLayout`. When I resize the Form or move the mouse, the lines disappear.  This happens with `TImage`, `TRectangle`, `TLayout`, and other components.

Can someone give me a solution for this graphic problem?

`TLayout` showing the lines:

[image]

`TLayout` after resizing the Form:

[image]

```pascal
var
  backRectangle: TRectangle;
  category, title: TLabel;
  icon: TImage;
  bar: TRectangle;
  background: TGridPanelLayout;
  lay1, layicon: TLayout;
begin
  backRectangle := TRectangle.Create(Self);
  with backRectangle do
  begin
    Height := 150;
    Align := TAlignLayout.top;
    Fill.Color := Talphacolors.White;
    Parent := Self;
    Stroke.Thickness := 0;
    Margins.Left := 20;
    Margins.Top := 20;
    Name := 'rectangle';
  end;

  background := TGridPanelLayout.Create(backRectangle);
  with background do
  begin
    Parent := backRectangle;
    Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    ColumnCollection.ClearAndResetID;
    ColumnCollection.BeginUpdate;

    with ColumnCollection.Add do
    begin
      Value := 100;
      SizeStyle := TGridPanelLayout.TSizeStyle.Percent;
    end;

    ColumnCollection.EndUpdate;
    RowCollection.Clear;
  end;

  lay1 := TLayout.Create(backRectangle);
  lay1.Parent := backRectangle;
  lay1.Align := TAlignLayout.client;
  background.AddObject(lay1);

  layicon := TLayout.Create(lay1);
  layicon.Parent := lay1;
  layicon.Align := TAlignLayout.client;

  category := TLabel.Create(backRectangle);
  with category do
  begin
    StyledSettings := [];
    AutoSize := true;
    Parent := lay1;
    Align := TAlignLayout.None;
    BeginUpdate;
    TextSettings.BeginUpdate;
    TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Roboto';
    TextSettings.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
    TextSettings.Font.Size := 16;
    Text := 'category';
    TextSettings.EndUpdate;
    Margins.Left := 25;
    Margins.Right := 0;
    Margins.Bottom := 6;
    Margins.Top:= 10;
    TabOrder := 0;
  end;

  bar := TRectangle.Create(backRectangle);
  bar.Width := 100;
  bar.Height := 3;
  bar.Fill.Color := $FF518CD2;
  bar.Parent := lay1;
  bar.Align := TAlignLayout.None;
  bar.Stroke.Thickness := 0;
  bar.Margins.Right := 20;

  icon := timage.Create(layicon);
  with icon do
  begin
    Parent := lay1;
    Width := 30;
    Margins.Left := 20;
    Margins.Right := 20;
    Margins.Bottom := 15;
    Margins.Top := 45;
    WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.fit;
    Align := TAlignLayout.FitLeft;
    try
      Bitmap.LoadFromFile('icon');
    except
    end;
  end;

  title := TLabel.Create(layicon);
  with title do
  begin
    StyledSettings := [];
    Parent := lay1;
    Text := '';
    Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
    TextSettings.Font.Family := 'Roboto';
    TextSettings.Font.Style := [];
    TextSettings.Font.Size := 16;
    Margins.Left := 10;
    TextSettings.VertAlign := TTextAlign.Center;
  end;
  bar.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
  category.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
end;
```

Comment: Which platform are you using here? I assume it's Windows. I tried your example and I was unable to reproduce the problem! Could it perhaps be because of the TText or TLabel components that aren't shown in your question, but which show in your image? Paste minimum reproducible example code so we can see the same results you see.

Comment: I'm using Windows, I edited the post with the code that I used to reproduce the problem in a new multi device application

Comment: Thanks. (Of course, I don't have your icon) I am still not able to reproduce the problem. Have you run your code on a different PC to see if it's not specific to your development PC?

Comment: I tried create a new application on a different PC and the problem still happens, I am using Delphi 10.3

Comment: I get this effect in our application too sometimes. I think its  an FMX rendering issue. Maybe check the quality central, or make an issue.

Comment: How you handle with this ? Are there some tip that you use ?

Comment: We can't really reproduce it in our application. Which is a work in progress still. So we didn't really dig for a solution yet. I tried your piece of coding, but this does not give me any problems when resizing (building for Windows). Did you try the application on various machines (with different specs etc)? I'm just thinking out loud here :)